# Application hangs or crashes when unloading WinInet

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, wininet

I have a VC++ application that uses WinInet. It does the following:

- calls `LoadLibrary()` to load WinInet.dll
- calls `InternetAttemptConnect()`
- calls `InternetOpen()`
- calls `InternetConnect()` providing `INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP` as `dwService`

If the last call fails (usually because of wrong password passed) `InternetConnect()` returns 0 and this should be handled by writing an error into the log and quitting the application.

When that happens the application calls `InternetCloseHandle()` for closing the handle returned by `InternetOpen()` and leaves `WinMain()`.

After that libraries unloading begins - either a static object holding a handle to wininet.dll is destriyed and `FreeLibrary()` is called or `FreeLibrary()` is called by Windows. In any case the call to `FreeLibrary()` either hangs or crashes.

Usually it hangs with the following call stack:

```
ntdll.dll!KiFastSystemCallRet()     
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()  + 0xc    
kernel32.dll!WaitForSingleObject()  + 0x12  
wininet.dll!InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll()  + 0xe3    
wininet.dll!InternetInitializeAutoProxyDll()  + 0x193e  
wininet.dll!771b159d()  
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk()  + 0x24  
ntdll.dll!LdrDisableThreadCalloutsForDll()  + 0x949 
kernel32.dll!FreeLibrary()  + 0x19  
MyApp.exe!$E5()  + 0x10 C++ <-presumably the static object destructor call
msvcr71.dll!doexit(int code=0, int quick=0, int retcaller=0)  Line 376  C
msvcr71.dll!exit(int code=0)  Line 303 + 0xd    C
MyApp.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup()  Line 406    C <-entry point of my application
kernel32.dll!RegisterWaitForInputIdle()  + 0x49
```

Sometimes it just crashes with no reasonable call stack to show. I suppose the problem is that WinInet has not been finalized properly and handling this requires some extra action and time.

Is there a workaround for this situation?

Comment: It only crashes when InternetConnect() returns 0, right? In the success case, it doesn't crash.

Comment: Are you using LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() explicitly?  If so, make sure that you declared the function pointers correctly -- provide your code that does the GetProcAddress() and cast.

Comment: I haven't tested that thorougly whether it stops smoothly when InternetConnect() succeeds. And yes, Loadlibrary() and GetProcAddress() are used explicitly and pointers declaration is right - it would just crash every other time otherwise.

Comment: can you make a minimal set of code that demonstrates this?

Comment: crash or hang?  For the crashes, are they the same stack as hang?  A summary from WinDBG would be good clues for folks to answer your question.

Comment: Do you check if InternetOpen() returns a valid handle? If not, try using InternetGetLastResponseInfo() after InternetConnect() returns 0 to see what is the error.